# Databricks Enable Logging

Tags: scala, databricks

Could anyone please let me know how I can enable Logging in my Databricks scala Notebooks ?
Also, where these log messages get logged, log file location and how can I access these logs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a general purpose cluster to execute notebook cells I assume you're interested in [Spark drivers\workers logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage#driver-logs)

Comment: Thanks! Spark drivers/workers logs are the default logs. If I need the scala notebook level custom logs (that I  can include in catch Exception block), could you let me know what options I have? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anyone let me know how to get the logs when I use logging in my Databricks scala notebook.

Comment: What does getting the logs mean ?

If you dig in the driver log4j logs you'll find your application logs as well. It's probably not practical to search through those `.txt` files.

Also by default you should see logged text under each executed cell.

Here's an how to send logs to Azure Monitor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/application-logs